# How to delete selected object using button in unity

Tags: c#, button, unity-game-engine

I have two objects and one button. First I have to select one object and if I click the button then the selected object have to be destroyed.

How I can destroy the object?

**Coding to get seleced object name:**

```
public class ClickAction : MonoBehaviour {
    public string on = null;
    public Destroyer destroy;

    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
            Ray toMouse = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit rhInfo;
            bool didHit = Physics.Raycast(toMouse, out rhInfo, 500.0f);
            if (didHit) {
                Debug.Log(rhInfo.collider.name);
            }               
        }  
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Destroy` method to destroy your object.

```
Destroy(rhInfo.collider.gameObject);
```

In your code:

```
///use `Destroy` in your code    
public class ClickAction : MonoBehaviour {
    public string on = null;
    public Destroyer destroy;
    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
            Ray toMouse = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit rhInfo;
            bool didHit = Physics.Raycast(toMouse, out rhInfo, 500.0f);
            if (didHit) {
                 Destroy(rhInfo.collider.gameObject);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: then you just need to put the code mentioned before instead of your Debug.Log() line

Answer (score 0):

An interesting point to not for javascript users to stumble upon this thread:

> Destroy is inherited from the UnityEngine.Object base class.
>   Javascript users should consider making a call to
>   UnityEngine.Object.Destroy, rather than Object.Destroy to avoid
>   references being resolved to the .Net System.Object class

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html